# JS: detect a dom mutation of a watched div (or change-event-listener to innerHTML)

Tags: javascript, dom, observable, onchange

:)

I'm using the [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/) WYSIWYG editor. The DIV is patched with a hidden textarea field.

The problem is that all changes are just synced onSubmit().

Now I need a way to listen for changes. For example to change backgound color of the field on changing content (inputs) *(flagged as unsaved)*. But there is no addEventListener for changed InnerHTML, as far as I know.
So maybe it's possible to use a callback function like a domMutationObserver. But I have no ideas how to deal with that.

**js code:**

```
let domField = document.querySelector('.contents .subpage[data-pagename="Index"][data-culture="en-US"] .nicEdit-main');
```

I can detect the selector of the editor div. So how to detect changes inside this element/node?

I read something about an "observer" to detect dom mutations. Maybe somebody can give me a simple and easy example.

Thx for everything. ;)

---

**EDIT:** And I hope we all agree that I won't set an interval (just to save browser performance). But yeah that could be a way. So watching for mutations or changing innerHTML of my DIV element.

**pseudo code:**

```
domElement.innerHTML.watch('change', elem => {
    elem.classList.add('changed'); //or unsaved
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect changes in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)

Answer (score 1):

maybe `Proxy` could solve it.when some properties of style has changed,`set` will invoke.

```js
    var app = document.getElementById('app')
    var handle = {
      get(target, property, value, receive) {
        return target[property]
      },
      set(target, property, value, receive) {
        // callback()
        Reflect.set(target, property, value)
      }
    }
    var a = new Proxy(app, handle)
    a.innerHTML = 2
    a.style.background = "red"
    a.style.height = "200px"
    a.style.width = "200px"
```

Comment: I'm not sure, what you want to show me here. Okay, this code is changing the background of my DIV box after a 2secs timeout.

But it doesn't seem to watch for DOM mutations or an changing innerHTML of my DIV element. And I hope we all agree that I won't set an interval (to save browser performance).

Comment: you could set proxy for your element,and set `callback` into `set`

Comment: Oohhh, okay. I see. This is interesting. :) 
But for the moment I'll use the onblur event to check changes (from loaded init). 
That protects browser performance.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, I managed to create an Observer.
Unfortunately, this fires with every single DOM change during runtime.

**js code:**

```
let domElement = document.querySelector('.contents .subpage[data-pagename="Index"] .culture[data-culture="de-DE"] .nicEdit-main');

let observer = new window.MutationObserver((e) => {
    console.log(domElement.innerHTML);
});

observer.observe(domElement, {
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true
});
```

In the meantime, I think that watching the blur event would be enough. Then it just should be checked whether the "new" innerHTML differs from the "old" (or initially loaded) innerHTML.

**js code:**

```
let domElement = document.querySelector('.contents .subpage[data-pagename="Index"] .culture[data-culture="de-DE"] .nicEdit-main');

domElement.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
    //check .innerHTML changed (compared to init value)
    alert('onblur');
});
```

Of course, this isn't a DOM observer / watching, but it costs the browser significantly less performance, if not each separate change fires, but only leave-focus interaction of the user and a manually check for .innerHTML changes.

Comment: "Unfortunately, this fires with every single DOM change during runtime." What about only setting the observer after the page has finished loading?